# How to convert one column into two columns

Tags: r

I have the following column:

| Client number | Reason for Leaving |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Death |
| 2 | WithDrawal |

... and so on

(note the column only contains deaths and withdrawals)

I want to split this column into two columns.
So that one column only contains deaths (the client who has not died can be left blank) and the other column only contains withdrawals (the client who has not withdrawn can be left blank).

| Client number | Reason for Leaving | Reason for Leaving |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Death |  |
| 2 |  | Withdrawal |

Comment: Happy to see that your question was answered! In the future, consider sharing example dataset using `dput`. This will allow members to easily recreate your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pivot_wider` after creating a separate column for each reason.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(col = match(Reason.for.Leaving, unique(Reason.for.Leaving))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = Reason.for.Leaving, 
              names_prefix = 'Reason')

#  Client.number Reason1 Reason2   
#          <int> <chr>   <chr>     
#1             1 Death   NA        
#2             2 NA      WithDrawal
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Client.number = 1:2, 
   Reason.for.Leaving = c("Death", "WithDrawal")), 
   row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```